# How to use Useref/EventTarget to set component's prop based on its childnodes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

What I am trying to implement is upon clicking each circle I want to get the radio button checked and set Avatar's prop 'border' to true(as marked in below code). I achieved the first goal but had no luck with latter one. Is there a good way to acheieve this?

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Field, ErrorMessage } from 'formik';
import FormikError from '../FormikError';
import Avatar from '../../../../atoms/avatar/avatar';
import Icon from '../../../../atoms/icon/icon';

const FormikRadio = ({ label, name, options, ...rest }) => {
    const [selected, setSelected] = useState('');
    const inputRef = useRef();

    const handleClick = (e) => {
        e.currentTarget.childNodes[1].checked = true;
        console.log(inputRef);
        setSelected(e.currentTarget);
    };

    return (
        <div className='form-control radio-group'>
            <Field name={name} {...rest}>
                {({ field }) => {
                    return options.map((option) => {
                        return (
                            <React.Fragment key={option.key}>
                                <Avatar onClick={(e) => handleClick(e)} ref={inputRef}>
                                    <Icon variant='AVATAR_KIWI' />
                                    <input
                                        type='radio'
                                        id={option.value}
                                        {...field}
                                        value={option.value}
                                        checked={field.value === option.value}
                                        border={I want this conditionally set if radio checked is true}
                                    />
                                </Avatar>
                            </React.Fragment>
                        );
                    });
                }}
            </Field>
            <ErrorMessage name={name} component={FormikError} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default FormikRadio;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set border={selected.childNodes[1].id === option.value}

Also, you can use id as selected

```js
<input
   type='radio'
   id={option.value}
   {...field}
   value={option.value}
   checked={field.value === option.value}
   border={selected.childNodes[1].id === option.value}
/>
```